# UrlFetch PUT is sending a Post Request?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, urllib, mlab, urlfetch

I am trying to update a document in a MongoDB database using the MongoLab Rest API http://docs.mongolab.com/data-api/.

In the documentation it says to use a PUT request to update documents within a collection with the update operator in the Body of the http request.

So, in accordance to the documentation I try the following:

```
        urlinsert = 'https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/ur_coursesniper/collections/classes?apiKey={key}&q={q}'
        urlinsert = urlinsert.format(q=querycheck, key=CONFIG["key"])
        form_fields = {
            "$push" : { "Users" : email},
        }
        form_data = urllib.urlencode(form_fields)
        result = urlfetch.fetch(url=urlinsert,
            payload=form_data,
            method=urlfetch.PUT,)
```

However, after this block of code executes the document within in the collection is not updated.

The HTTP response I receive is

```
2015-08-16 10:55:45,129 module.py:812] default: "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 91
```

This is perplexing since it says the response is both successful and a POST.

Any ideas on what exactly is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`str.format()` *returns* the formatted string, it does not update it in place. Thus

```
urlinsert.format(q=querycheck, key=CONFIG["key"])
```

has no affect on the value of `urlinsert`, and the query string `apiKey={key}&q={q}` is sent. Try this instead:

```
urlinsert = urlinsert.format(q=querycheck, key=CONFIG["key"])
```

It would be interesting to see what is contained in the body of the response from mongodb - it might contain an error message.

---

**Update**

Now that you are setting the `Content-Type: application/json` header you need to send JSON data in the payload. `"$push" : { "Users" : email}` is not valid JSON. You can use `json.dumps()` to convert the `form_fields` dictionary to a valid JSON string:

```
import json

urlinsert = 'https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/ur_coursesniper/collections/classes?apiKey={key}&q={q}'
urlinsert = urlinsert.format(q=querycheck, key=CONFIG["key"])
form_fields = {"$push": {"Users": email}}

result = urlfetch.fetch(url=urlinsert,
    payload=json.dumps(form_fields),
    method=urlfetch.PUT,
    headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
```

Comment: just fixed this...still sends a POST request and no update recognized in the DB :(. Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the body of the response for an error message?

Comment: heres some progress! i got the error message { "message" : "No Content-Type set, expecting 'application/json'."}, so I added the field        headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}))
  to the urlfetch.fetch() call. I am still getting a post and I have no idea why....

Comment: The payload that you are sending is not JSON. I have updated my answer with details on how to fix that. Not sure about POST instead of PUT... that's a bit odd.

Comment: BTW why don't you use `pymongo` or other library as recommended in the mongodb documentation?

Comment: worked perfectly...thank you so much, a big duh for me. I still get a post but it seems to be working fine now. Awesome!

Comment: googleappengine has weird restrictions which basically blocks the port that the mongo driver uses.